# Do i have to repeatedly create/delete db entries for each test?

Tags: python, pytest, playwright

I have Playwright/Pytest regression tests which are run on a uat server (not locally on my machine, so I cannot just create a db fixture with dummy data). I have tests that create, edit, then delete a database entry through the website (automated with Playwright).

I can think of two options.

1- The tests will be dependent on each other and must be ran in this order: test_create_user, test_edit_user, test_delete_user. Not good as tests should be independent of each other.

2- The tests will not be dependent on each other, but I must crate/delete the data during each test. This doesn't seem right as surely I shouldn't have to repeatedly create/delete test data in order to keep tests independent. Example:

```
test_create_user
- load website
- create user
- use expect statement to verify it worked
- delete user

test_edit_user
- load website
- create user
- edit user
- use expect statement to verify it worked
- delete user

test_delete_user
- load website
- create user
- delete user
- use expect statement to verify it worked
```

What is the best way to run multiple tests which require dummy data, without having to crate/delete it each time using Playwright/Pytest, keeping in mind that this testing is done on a live server/db and not locally?

Ps - I know Playwright has setup/teardown, where I could create db entries in startup and delete them in teardown, but this doesn't help with tests such as when creating/deleting users.

Thank you.

Comment: There’s no objective answer to this question. As far as I can tell, there’s no valid answer either, since you’ve given conflicting constraints (no setup/tear down, but use in multiple tests and don’t reuse across tests??). But the larger problem is this is a design decision which is opinion based and ultimately up to you. See the guide to [ask] and make sure your question is objective, answerable, and includes your attempt (in code) at answering the problem.

Comment: Pytest itself addresses use cases such as this. I would recommend further reading -- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/simple.html#incremental-testing-test-steps

Answer (score 1):

Each test must be independent from the rest. As you said, your test_delete_user can not depend on your test_create_user.

What I do?
For my test test_create_user:

- Load website
- Create user
- Use expect statement to verify it worked
- In case you don't want to leave trash in the DB, then you can have another DB query for deleting that new user, but if this query does not work, the test should not fail.

For my test test_edit_user:

- Load website
- I always edit same user
- Use expect statement to verify it worked

For my test test_delete_user:

- Precondition: I have a query to DB to insert an user, then my test starts.
- Load website
- Delete user
- Use expect statement to verify it worked

I do it like this because each test is independent, lets imagine the function for deleting an user is working but your function for create user is not working, if your test were like this:

- Load website
- Create user
- Delete user
- Use expect statement to verify it worked

You will get a falsy error saying that your test_delete_user is not working, but actually it is.